# deactivate account from firebase chat app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-storage

i'm using the firebase database for my chat application, When i click on the deactivate button it deletes the user from the Authentication section of firebase but not from the database section of firebase and my all user activity retrieve the user data from the database section. because of this when a user deactivate his account it get delete, but his account is still visible to the other user. below this i'm attaching my codes..

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ImageView ivCamera;

    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

    private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mStatus;

    private Button mProfileBtn;
    private Button mDeactivateBtn;
    //private Button mImageBtn;

    private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

    private StorageReference mImageStorage;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


        mDisplayImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_image);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_name);
        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_status);

        mProfileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_profile_btn);
        mDeactivateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deactivate_btn);
        ivCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


        String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);

        mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);




        mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                final String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();


                mName.setText(name);
                mStatus.setText(status);



                if (!image.equals("default")) {

                    //Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.avatar).into(mDisplayImage);
                    Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar).into(mDisplayImage, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                            Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.avatar).into(mDisplayImage);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        //ivGallery =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);

        //ivGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //   @Override
        // public void onClick(View view) {

        //}
        //});

        mProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String name_value = mName.getText().toString();
                String status_value = mStatus.getText().toString();

                Intent status_Intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, StatusActivity.class);
                status_Intent.putExtra("status_value", status_value);
                status_Intent.putExtra("name_value", name_value);

                startActivity(status_Intent);
            }

        });


        ivCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PICK);


            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri imageUri = data.getData();


            CropImage.activity(imageUri).setAspectRatio(1, 1).start(this);

            //Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SettingsActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Image.....");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we upload and process the image.");
                mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();


                File thumb_filePath = new File(resultUri.getPath());

                String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();

                Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this)
                        .setMaxWidth(200)
                        .setMaxHeight(200)
                        .setQuality(75)
                        .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();

                StorageReference filePath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");

                final StorageReference thumb_filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child("thumbs").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            final String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_filepath.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                            uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                                    String thumb_downloadUrl = thumb_task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                    if (thumb_task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        Map update_hashMap = new HashMap();
                                        update_hashMap.put("image", download_url);
                                        update_hashMap.put("thumb_image", thumb_downloadUrl);

                                        mUserDatabase.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Success Uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {

                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error in Uploading thumbnail.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error in Uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }


    public static String random() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        StringBuilder randomStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int randomLength = generator.nextInt(10);
        char tempChar;
        for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++) {
            tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
            randomStringBuilder.append(tempChar);
        }
        return randomStringBuilder.toString();
    }



            public void deactivate(View view)
            {
              FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user!=null)
            {
             mProgressDialog.setTitle("Deactivate Account");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Deactivating...");
              mProgressDialog.show();
              mUserDatabase.child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).removeValue();
             user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account is Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         finish();
                         Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                         startActivity(intent);
                     } else {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account could not be Deactivate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                     mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                 }
             });
              }
            }
}
```

i want that when the user deactivate his account it will not visible anymore in the all user activity

Comment: When you delete account of user.
You should delete all nodes attaching to that user. so that any activity related to user will not be visible to other users.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to doing this.

1. When you delete account of user. You should delete all nodes attaching to that user. so that any activity related to user will not be visible to other users.!
2. if you don't want to remove from database section. you can put another key value with the name of status. if user status is deleted or disable. don't fetch the data of that user in activity.

Hope this will help you to answer your question.
if you've still questions in your mind, you can ask.

For deleting child:

```
 rootRef.child(node).removeValue();
```

Simple deleting the node.

you can customize it according to your need.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me the codes for deleting the data from database

Comment: thanks, i will wait, actually i'm doing a college project so it'll be good for me if i'll get your help as soon as possible

Comment: I've updated @rbshubham . please mark as solution if it helps you :)

Comment: It will delete all the node so be careful

Comment: i have updated according to you but still not deleting the user data from database

Comment: DatabaseReference delete = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Node");
delete.setValue(null);
Try this

Comment: when the account is deleted ,app is crashing

Comment: @rbshubham show me your logcat when app is crashing

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.shubh.buddychat.SettingsActivity$1.onDataChange(SettingsActivity.java:97)

Comment: You're getting null data from firebase or might be your variables hold null data.
check your reference or data is it exist or not |
search datasnap exists function for checking whether data is null or not.

Comment: Post another question with logcat report and relevant code just

Comment: i have posted new question

Answer (score 0):

DatabaseReference delete = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Node");
                delete.setValue(null);